# Can I let a function call soft coded?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, visual-c++

I'd like to make a unit testing driver.
It reads `tests.txt` with content like:

```
I32 cdecl32 func(in I32, in szC8P32, out I32P32, out sC8P32)
in  in      out out     ret out out ret ...
16  test    5   test2   1
```

The callee has a declaration like this:

```
int __cdecl func(const int, const char*, int*, char*);
```

The test driver use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to get the address of the function.
But, the driver will NOT include the declaration of `func`. It will be used for testing other function type. Like a universal tool.
The arguments should be given dynamicly by parsing the `tests.txt`.

Is it possible? How should I do?

Comment: I'd say that it's even easier code this kind of thing in assembly, since you only need to push the right arguments into the stack and `call` the memory address. trying to implement such thing in strongly typed-statically compiled language is a mess.

Comment: @DavidHaim: C is not **strongly** typed!

Comment: @Olaf it's strongly typed but weakly checked

Comment: @DavidHaim: Please revisit the definitions. It is weakly typed, e.g. because of automatic conversion from a "larger" to a "smaller" type and automatic type coercion. For instance: `int i; ... char ch = i;`.

Comment: @DavidHaim: That's of course assuming a system where arguments are passed on the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is tricky. You will have to match the declaration of the function with the definition in the TXT file. If they do not match exactly you will have undefined behavior.

Anyway, you have two options:

1. The testing driver will emit a C file with a function prototype, and the run the C compiler to generate the needed code.
2. Use [`libffi`](https://sourceware.org/libffi/), a library designed to do exactly what you need.

Comment: Ah... enlightened me. Sorry for my noob question...